# tinymce with babel: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning (when calling EmberJS npm start)

Tags: node.js, npm, ember.js, babeljs, tinymce-5

I have installed tinymce in my EmberJS application. When I run `npm start` or even `npm run build`, I get an error like so:

```
[Package /assets/vendor.js]/home/ikirkpat/Projects/proj_name/frontend/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:98681
                throw e;

Error: Debug Failure.
    at Object.assertDefined (/home/ikirkpat/Projects/proj_name/frontend/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:2227:24)
    at /home/ikirkpat/Projects/proj_name/frontend/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:39474:34
    at Object.filter (/home/ikirkpat/Projects/proj_name/frontend/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:513:31)
    at serializeAsClass (/home/ikirkpat/Projects/proj_name/frontend/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:39472:48)
    at serializeSymbolWorker (/home/ikirkpat/Projects/proj_name/frontend/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:39203:29)
    at serializeSymbol (/home/ikirkpat/Projects/proj_name/frontend/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:39144:38)
    at /home/ikirkpat/Projects/proj_name/frontend/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:39119:25
    at Map.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at visitSymbolTable (/home/ikirkpat/Projects/proj_name/frontend/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:39118:33)
    at symbolTableToDeclarationStatements (/home/ikirkpat/Projects/proj_name/frontend/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:38989:17)
⠧ building... [SassCompiler](node:14526) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Debug Failure.
    at CommandCoordinator.dispatchResponse (/home/ikirkpat/Projects/proj_name/frontend/node_modules/stagehand/lib/command-coordinator.js:54:69)
    at CommandCoordinator.<anonymous> (/home/ikirkpat/Projects/proj_name/frontend/node_modules/stagehand/lib/command-coordinator.js:43:29)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at /home/ikirkpat/Projects/proj_name/frontend/node_modules/stagehand/lib/command-coordinator.js:7:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (/home/ikirkpat/Projects/proj_name/frontend/node_modules/stagehand/lib/command-coordinator.js:3:12)
    at CommandCoordinator.messageReceived (/home/ikirkpat/Projects/proj_name/frontend/node_modules/stagehand/lib/command-coordinator.js:40:16)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at emit (internal/child_process.js:876:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:85:21)

(node:14526) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Debug Failure.
    at CommandCoordinator.dispatchResponse (/home/ikirkpat/Projects/proj_name/frontend/node_modules/stagehand/lib/command-coordinator.js:54:69)
    at CommandCoordinator.<anonymous> (/home/ikirkpat/Projects/proj_name/frontend/node_modules/stagehand/lib/command-coordinator.js:43:29)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at /home/ikirkpat/Projects/proj_name/frontend/node_modules/stagehand/lib/command-coordinator.js:7:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (/home/ikirkpat/Projects/proj_name/frontend/node_modules/stagehand/lib/command-coordinator.js:3:12)
    at CommandCoordinator.messageReceived (/home/ikirkpat/Projects/proj_name/frontend/node_modules/stagehand/lib/command-coordinator.js:40:16)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at emit (internal/child_process.js:876:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:85:21)
(node:14526) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 15)
```

For background, this was building perfectly before. Then I merged my teams master branch into my feature branch to fix merge conflicts and now it won't build.

So here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "...",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "description": "...",
  "repository": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "author": "",
  "directories": {
    "doc": "doc",
    "test": "tests"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "ember build",
    "codegen": "graphql-codegen",
    "lint:hbs": "ember-template-lint .",
    "lint:js": "eslint .",
    "start": "ember serve --ssl --secure-proxy false --proxy https://localhost:5001 --environment local",
    "test": "ember test"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ember/edition-utils": "^1.1.1",
    "@ember/jquery": "^1.1.0",
    "@ember/optional-features": "^1.1.0",
    "@glimmer/component": "^1.0.0",
    "@types/ember": "^3.1.1",
    "@types/ember-qunit": "^3.4.7",
    "@types/ember__test-helpers": "^0.7.9",
    "@types/qunit": "^2.9.0",
    "@types/rsvp": "^4.0.3",
    "apollo-link-error": "^1.1.12",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.2",
    "broccoli-asset-rev": "^3.0.0",
    "ember-animated": "^0.9.0",
    "ember-apollo-client": "2.0.0",
    "ember-auto-import": "^1.5.3",
    "ember-cli": "~3.15.1",
    "ember-cli-app-version": "^3.2.0",
    "ember-cli-babel": "^7.13.0",
    "ember-cli-dependency-checker": "^3.2.0",
    "ember-cli-deploy": "^1.0.2",
    "ember-cli-deploy-build": "^2.0.0",
    "ember-cli-deploy-s3": "^1.4.0",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars": "^4.2.0",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^2.0.1",
    "ember-cli-sass": "^10.0.1",
    "ember-cli-sri": "^2.1.1",
    "ember-cli-typescript": "^3.1.1",
    "ember-cli-typescript-blueprints": "^3.0.0",
    "ember-cli-uglify": "^3.0.0",
    "ember-cli-update": "^0.49.6",
    "ember-css-modules": "^1.3.0-beta.1",
    "ember-css-modules-sass": "^1.0.1",
    "ember-drag-drop": "atomicobject/ember-drag-drop#feature/horizontal-sorting-improvements",
    "ember-export-application-global": "^2.0.1",
    "ember-fetch": "^7.0.0",
    "ember-intl": "^4.2.2",
    "ember-load-initializers": "^2.1.1",
    "ember-maybe-import-regenerator": "^0.1.6",
    "ember-paper": "^1.0.0-beta.26",
    "ember-qunit": "^4.6.0",
    "ember-resolver": "^7.0.0",
    "ember-source": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/builds.emberjs.com/beta/shas/49ae818907447d9c469d68b297060f00728ffb5a.tgz",
    "ember-template-lint": "^1.5.0",
    "ember-test-selectors": "^2.1.0",
    "ember-tooltips": "^3.4.2",
    "ember-welcome-page": "^4.0.0",
    "ember-wormhole": "^0.5.5",
    "eslint": "^6.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-ember": "^7.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^10.0.0",
    "graphql": "^14.5.8",
    "liquid-fire": "^0.31.0",
    "loader.js": "^4.7.0",
    "qunit-dom": "^0.9.2",
    "sass": "^1.23.3",
    "typescript": "^3.7.2"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8.* || >= 10.*"
  },
  "ember": {
    "edition": "octane"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@ember/render-modifiers": "^1.0.2",
    "@glimmer/tracking": "^0.14.0-alpha.1",
    "@graphql-codegen/cli": "^1.9.1",
    "@graphql-codegen/near-operation-file-preset": "^1.9.1",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript": "^1.9.1",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript-compatibility": "^1.9.1",
    "@graphql-codegen/typescript-operations": "^1.9.1",
    "@simple-dom/interface": "^1.4.0",
    "@types/faker": "^4.1.8",
    "@types/lodash-es": "^4.17.3",
    "@types/tinymce": "^4.5.24",
    "apollo-cache-inmemory": "^1.6.3",
    "apollo-link": "^1.2.13",
    "apollo-link-batch-http": "^1.2.13",
    "bufferutil": "^4.0.1",
    "cldr-core": "^36.0.0",
    "ember-click-outside": "^1.3.0",
    "ember-concurrency-decorators": "^1.0.0",
    "ember-file-upload": "^2.7.1",
    "ember-hacky-set-value": "0.0.1",
    "es6-promise": "^4.2.8",
    "faker": "^4.1.0",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "lodash-es": "^4.17.15",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "tinymce": "^5.2.1"
  }
}
```

It was builing until the ember-hacky-set-value package was introduced so I wonder if that's the problem. But that seems like a completely unrelated change that shouldn't have effected tinymce. So maybe it's something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change line "typescript": "^3.7.2" -> "typescript": "~3.7.2"

Somehow your typescript got updated to 3.8, which has this issue: https://github.com/typed-ember/ember-cli-typescript/issues/1103

Comment: I wish I could up vote this like 100 times. I have spent wayy too much time grasping at any solution and searching for answers. This worked! Thank you!